# Duplicate Data how to remove

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hotels_data table
[image: Hotel Data Table]

hotel_rooms table

[image: hotel_rooms table]

MYSQL QUERY

```
$pdo = $dbo->prepare('SELECT distinct hotels_data.*, hotel_rooms.hid, hotel_rooms.room_name, hotel_rooms.price 
                    FROM hotels_data
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN hotel_rooms
                    ON hotels_data.hotel_id = hotel_rooms.hid
                ');
```

OUTPUTING THE DATA

i loop the Hotel rooms

```
$row = $pdo->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach($row as $rows){        
        print '
       <!-- Listing -->
             <div class="list_hotels_box">
                <ul class="list_hotels_ul">
                    <li style="display:block;">
                        <img src="../img/hotel_img.png" alt="" style="width: 180px; height:180px;"/>
                    </li>
                    <li style="width: 100%;">
                        <a href="javascript:void()"><h3 class="clear-top">'.$rows->hotel_name.'<span><?php print $star; ?></span></h3></a>
                        <p>'.$rows->hotel_address.', '.$rows->hotel_state.''.$rows->hotel_country.' </p>

                       <div id="rooms">
                       <p>
                            <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
                                        ';
                                        foreach($row as $td){
                                            if($td->hotel_id == $rows->hid){
                                                print 
                                            '
                                                <tr>
                                                        <td>'.$td->room_name.'</td>
                                                        <td align="right" style="color: darkorange;"><strong><sup>RM</sup>'.$td->price.'</strong></td>
                                                </tr>
                                               ';
                                            };
                                        } ;
                            print '
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="a" style="font-size: 11px;">See All Rooms</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                        </p>
                       </div>
                    </li>
                    <div align="right">
                        <li>
                            <h4><small>Rating</small> <strong>8.5</strong></h4>
                            <span class="help-block clear">"0" Reviews</span>
                            <button onclick="alert(\'Not operational yet\')" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Book Now</button>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- Listing -->
                ';
```

Here is the output 
i have Hotel Sample & Hotel Sample 2 but Hotel Sample has outputted 2
 i think its bcoz of the 2 rooms
so my problem is how do i remove the duplicate data

Please assist me. TQ

sorry if i didn't make myself very clear
[image: Output]

Comment: Use group by hotel_id

Comment: The problem comes from the way you decided to write your script and especially your SQL query. The way it's designed will return you sum{i : 0 -> m}( n(i) ) rows where "n" equals the amount of hotels for hotel "i", that's why you'll get 3 rows and not only 2 (1 for each hotel)

Comment: Check this [link](http://shaheerulhaq.com/delete-duplicate-records-mysql/)

Comment: If you want to keep a single SQL query, when you iterate over your rows; you would have to remind you of the hotel id you previously encountered. If for the current row the hotel id is the same compared to the last one, then you do not need to create another <div class="list_hotels_box">

Comment: @Jonathan you're welcome, feel free to give any feedback on this "solution" :) Honza Haering's solution  below is good too if you don't mind using 2  SQL queries

Comment: you see the reason why it output 3 it's bcoz of the hotel_rooms.table bcoz Hotel Sample has 2 rooms(eg. Room 1 & Room 2 ) so foreach loop makes it 2 separating Room 1 to another div & Room 2 another div but the hotel details like name,img,ratings are the same, i wanted to make the 2 Rooms 2gether so that's why i loop the the tables to appear intact, it did good, just that the duplicated one follows all well, So as u said @Cr3aHal0 the problems lies where i write my SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to simply split to 2 queries, like:

```
SELECT * FROM hotels_data;
```

And then rooms query inside your hotels loop:

```
SELECT hid, room_name, price FROM hotel_rooms WHERE hid = :hotel_id
```

This assumes you are using [binded parameters](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) and bind the `$rows->hotel_id` to `:hotel_id` parameter.

You could also use `GROUP BY hotel_id`, but then you won't get all the rooms for your hotels, unless you use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and parse the concatenated rooms values.

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't figure this one out, so instead i'll just go with your answer to do a slit query.